# Why aren't my nested SetTimeouts working with Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, settimeout, setinterval

I currently have code that looks something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import testimonials from './testimonials';
import {INTERVAL, FADE_OUT_ANIMATION_TIME, FADE_IN_ANIMATION_TIME} from './config';

class Carousel extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.startCarousel = this.startCarousel.bind(this);
    this.currentIdx = 0;
  }

  startCarousel = () => {
    this.intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      const {currentIdx, carouselContainer} = this;
      const testimonials = carouselContainer.children;
      const nextIdx = currentIdx + 1 !== testimonials.length ? currentIdx + 1 : 0;

      testimonials[currentIdx].classList.add('fadeOut');
      setTimeout(() => {
        testimonials[currentIdx].classList.add('hide');
        testimonials[currentIdx].classList.remove('fadeOut');

        testimonials[nextIdx].classList.remove('hide');
        testimonials[nextIdx].classList.add('fadeIn');
        setTimeout(() => testimonials[nextIdx].classList.remove('fadeIn'), FADE_IN_ANIMATION_TIME);
      }, FADE_OUT_ANIMATION_TIME);

      this.currentIdx = nextIdx;
    }, INTERVAL);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.startCarousel();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalID);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Carousel__container" ref={(ele) => this.carouselContainer = ele} >
        {testimonials.map(renderTestimonials)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Carousel;
```

All I'm doing is cycling through different elements being rendered inside of my carousel container, changing the classnames around every interval to trigger animations and hide/reveal elements. The interval and timeout times for reference:

```
export const INTERVAL = 8500;
export const FADE_OUT_ANIMATION_TIME = 800;
export const FADE_IN_ANIMATION_TIME = 1200;
```

This works on Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Edge, but not Internet Explorer 11. The carousel never cycles away from the first element. From what I can tell, this doesn't seem to be a CSS issue as the animations properly trigger and animate when I manually add the relevant classnames in the developer console. The `[DOMElement].classList.add/remove` methods seem to work fine as well. I tried manually recreating the above `setInterval` code in the IE11 console and it seems like there might be a problem with the nested `setTimeout`s in the `setInterval`?

From what I observed it seems like the `fadeIn` classname was correctly being added but the `hide` classname wasn't being removed except when it cycled back to the very first element in the container.

Anyone have any idea about what could be happening here? Any advice on how I could make this work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is related to the currentIdx value setting, Please refer to the following code, it works well on my side:

```
export const INTERVAL = 8500;
export const FADE_OUT_ANIMATION_TIME = 800;
export const FADE_IN_ANIMATION_TIME = 1200;
var currentIdx =0;

  class Carousel extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props); 
    }

    startCarousel = () => {
      this.intervalID = setInterval(() => { 
        const testimonials = document.getElementsByClassName("imagecontent");
        const nextIdx = currentIdx + 1 !== testimonials.length ? currentIdx + 1 : 0;

        testimonials[currentIdx].classList.add('fadeOut');
        setTimeout(function () {
          testimonials[currentIdx].classList.add('hide');
          testimonials[currentIdx].classList.add('fadeOut');

          testimonials[nextIdx].classList.remove('hide');
          testimonials[nextIdx].classList.add('fadeIn');
          setTimeout(function () {
              console.log("nested settimeout");
              return testimonials[nextIdx].classList.remove('fadeIn');
          }, FADE_IN_ANIMATION_TIME);
          currentIdx =  currentIdx + 1 !== testimonials.length ? currentIdx + 1 : 0;
      }, FADE_OUT_ANIMATION_TIME);
      }, INTERVAL);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div >
            <input type="button" value="Start Carousel" onClick={ this.startCarousel} />
            <br />
          <div className="imagecontent image1">
          </div>
          <div className="imagecontent hide image2">
          </div>
          <div className="imagecontent hide image3">
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

The result as below:

[image]